# Mobile screen shows "loading"

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to to change image when a user rotates his mobile and to adjust the image to the screen size.

I came up with this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

 $(function () {

            setInterval(function () {
                checkMobilePosition();
            }, 1500);
        });


        function checkMobilePosition() {

            var height = getRealContentHeight();

            if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90) { // horizontal

                $(".aa").html(" <img src='Files/horizontal.jpg'  style='height:" + height + "px; width:100%;' />  ");

            }
            else { // vertical
                $(".aa").html(" <img src='Files/vertical.jpg'  style='height:" + height + "px; width:100%;' />  ");
            }
        }


        function getRealContentHeight() {

            var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
            var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
            var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
            var viewport_height = $(window).height();
            var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
            if ((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
                content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
            }

            return content_height;
        }
```

I am not sure if this code is the right way to do it but it works.

Anyway, the problem is the "loading" text I am having at the bottom of the page which I want to hide,  It's coming from  `mobile-1.3.2.min.js` script.

I was trying to use:

```
 $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
```

But this does not work.

Comment: use [`orientationchange`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) event instead of custom function. try it without `getRealContentHeight` function.

Comment: I changed it according your recommendation to 'orientationchange'. The event is fired upon screen rotation! Thanks. but I still see "Loading" at the bottom of the screen

Comment: are you testing it on android device?

Comment: i guess this is a common problem on android devices, try it on iOS.

Comment: There is some problem in configuration. Make sure you have added all us files in right order.